# Which is correct combination of versions of cucumber-jvm parallel, maven surefire and compiler to be configured for running test cases in parallel

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I am new to cucumber-jvm parallel plugin and want to understand 2 things basically -

**First - Which is correct combination of version i shall choose of cucumber-jvm parallel plugin, maven surefire and compiler plugin**

**Second - what is difference between cucumber-jvm implementation supporting parallel execution from V 4.0 and cucumber-jvm-parallel plugin**

**There are 2 phases people configure in cucumber-jvm-parallel plugin. Goal as validate or generateRunners. Can someone guide me whts the difference between these 2.**

```
             <id>generateRunners</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                </goals>
```

Is there any mandatory configuring missing in below jvm implementation

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generateRunners</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>


<glue>com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional</glue>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features/functional/</featuresDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
                        <format>json,html</format>
                        <tags>"~@ignored"</tags>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Please guide me as this is making me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So overall picture is, if we are using cucumber v 4.0.0 or above then we shall not use cucumber-jvm parallel plugin. Because one of the main principle of Cucumber 4.0.0 implementation is to provide support to parallel execution and coming to Maven Surefire version, we can use latest one as well i.e. 3.0.0-M3.

Answer (score 2):

Maven Surefire has two levels of parallel execution for JUnit tests. It can run individual classes in parallel and it can provide a scheduler to test runners that correctly implement the `ParentRunner`. Normally this is used to run methods in parallel by the `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Until version v4 Cucumber did not correctly implement `ParentRunner` so feature files could not be executed in parallel using the scheduler.

As explained in the [cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin/README](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin#cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin-) the plugin will create an individual runner class for each feature. This means that parallel execution depends on Surefires ability to run classes in parallel rather then its ability to provide a scheduler.

If you are using Cucumber v4 you should not use the parallel plugin. For all but a few limited use cases there are no benefits to doing so and a whole slew of downsides.

The [cucumber-jvm/junit/README.md](http://%20https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/v4.2.3/junit#parallel-execution-with-maven) describes how to configure surefire parallel execution (the latest stable version is `surefire:2.22.1` and should work).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>both</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mpkorstanje for sharing the valuable information